# Sphinx docs not displaying properly on Read the Docs

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I have written some [documentation](https://pyoeis.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html) for a Python module with Sphinx. It builds and displays the HTML perfectly on my computer. However, I have been maintaining a Read the Docs version and that is not displaying properly. When I checked it when the docs were more sparse, it worked but it has since stopped.

The API page (linked) should have more methods detailed than it does. When I look at the raw .rst files on GitHub, they contain the information but it doesn't display on RTD.

I changed the folder structure for the project when I put it on PyPI, so I'm wondering whether it's that but I can't see how to fix it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Can you point out a specific place in the sources that isn't properly shown on RTD?

Comment: It turns out that I had used Requests without putting it in the requirements file. I just added it and now it builds fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I had used Requests without putting it in the requirements file. I just added it and now it builds fine.